# Edit post arg for specific Wordpress category

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have this in my loop:

```html
<?php
    $args=array(
    'cat' => $select_blog_category,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'paged' => $paged
    );
    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
$featured_image_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'blog-square' ); 
$featured_image = $featured_image_array[0];
?>
```

I want this loop to display a specific category. I thought I could do this by changing:

```html
'cat' => $select_blog_category
```

to this (my post category):

```html
'cat' => 'upcoming-2'
```

But it doesn't work. I love everything else about how this code is displaying my posts, just want to filter it, thanks!

I also need to add another loop on the same page with a different category. Can I have two loops on the same page? So far every attempt I have tried at copying the code to a new section has resulted in a black white page, which tells me I'm doing something wrong.

I only come here as a last resort, not because I want someone to do my work, so I really appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: I tried this too: while ( $wp_query->have_posts('cat=18') ) : $wp_query->the_post();        but that didn't work either

Comment: maybe you looking for this answer?: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/page-navigation-doesnt-work-4

Comment: Here's how the arg $select_blog_category is defined:     $select_blog_category = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), BRANKIC_VAR_PREFIX."select_blog_category", true);